# View вытесняет другое view из макета

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

После второго EditText должна располагаться кнопка.
Но почему-то этот второй EditText выпихивает ее из макета.
Как решить проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Второй EditText имеет параметр `layout_width="match_parent"`, потому и вытесняет кнопку. Можете попробовать организовать верстку через `layout_weight`, или обернуть LinearLayout в RelativeLayout, кнопку вынести в RelativeLayout с креплением на правый край, а LinearLayout закрепить с левого края до кнопки.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, попробую.